# Change Image On Hover Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have done my research and looked at tons of things, but none of them are working for me. This is my code at the moment. The original image displays fine, but nothing happens when I hover.

**Javascript** (In `<head>`)

```
<script>
    function onHover()
    {
        $("#news").attr('src', 'img/newsHover.png');
    }

    function offHover()
    {
        $("#news").attr('src', 'img/news.png');
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="news" onmouseover="onHover();" onmouseout="offHover();" height="100px" width="100px" src="img/news.png"></a>
```

Comment: Your code is correct. Please check console for any other errors.

Comment: The code is correct. Check image paths and the console for errors. Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqznem8z/)

Comment: While you are using jQuery, you might have a look at [jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). Taking the onmouse from the html may make your page better maintainable

Comment: I think it is because of "/" at the beginning of your image path.Change "/img/newsHover.png" to "img/newsHover.png".

Comment: Console reports `"$" is not defined` and I changed the path to remove the first / but it still wouldn't work. .hover doesn't work either, that is what I first tried. Maybe the problem is with .attr?

Comment: Have you include JQuery inside your html page?

Comment: Only this is needed <img id="news" onmouseover="this.src='img/newsHover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/news.png'" height="100px" width="100px" src="img/news.png">

Comment: Thanks @abhiklpm, your suggestion worked. Post it as an answer and I can close the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pure java script answer, no need of any external functions or jquery

```
<img id="news" onmouseover="this.src='img/newsHover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/news.png'" height="100px" width="100px" src="img/news.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a good reason for what you're doing, but are you sure you need to use JavaScript?

If you're not doing anything fancy then it would probably be better to use the CSS hover selector: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: A more extensive explanation can be found at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

Comment: I usually use CSS, but I'm working with circle images and I don't want to have a square div with a circle image background. Perfectionism I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

this is very easy example, not animation:

**HTML:**

```
<img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/128x128/apps/clean.png'>
```

**use jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').hover(
        function(){$(this).attr("src","https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/128x128/apps/exit.png")},
        function(){$(this).attr("src","https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/128x128/apps/clean.png")}
    );
});
```

[Example Not Animation](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivoss/e9dct3rr/)

---

And this is example with animation:

**HTML:**

```
<img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/128x128/apps/clean.png' class='clean' >
<img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/128x128/apps/exit.png' class='exit' >
```

**CSS:**

```
img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

**use jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".exit").hide();

    $(".clean").hover(function(){
        $(".clean").fadeOut();
        $(".exit").fadeIn();
    });    

    $(".clean").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".exit").fadeOut();
        $(".clean").fadeIn();
    });    

});
```

[Example With Animation](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivoss/e9dct3rr/1/)

Comment: Tried your code, the example without animation worked on the site you linked to, but not on mine. Maybe there's a problem with the image file.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use only this example:

```
<img 
    src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/128x128/apps/clean.png' 
    onmouseover="this.src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/128x128/apps/exit.png'"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/128x128/apps/clean.png'"
    height="100px"
    width="100px"
    id="news"
>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivoss/e9dct3rr/2/)